# How to prove that $\frac{1}{x^4+y^4} e^{-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}\to0$ when $(x,y)\to (0,0) $?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> How can I calculate the limit 
>   $$
> \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{1}{x^4+y^4} e^{-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}
> $$
>   and show that it is zero?

When switching to polar coordinates, I get:
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{1}{r^4 (\cos^4 \theta+\sin^4 \theta) } e^{-\frac{1}{r^2}}
$$
but I have no idea how to show the term $\frac{1}{r^4 (\cos^4 \theta+\sin^4 \theta) }$ is bounded.

Comment: Would it be valid to determine the limit of the function as $y$ approaches $x,$ and when $x$ approaches $0$?

Comment: no. because there are instances where the limit on one path is some constant, but on another path the limit is another constant, so the limit does not exist

Comment: Try to use the fact that $\cos^4\theta+\sin^4\theta$ is never zero.

Comment: An expression for $\cos^4\theta+\sin^4\theta$ is also given in this post: [Prove that $\sin^4\theta+\cos^4\theta=\frac{3+\cos4\theta}{4}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1936121).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show that $\cos^4\theta+\sin^4\theta$ never gets too small.  A nice way to do this is to show

$$\begin{align}
\cos^4\theta+\sin^4\theta
&=(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)^2-2\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta\\
&=1-{1\over2}(2\sin\theta\cos\theta)^2\\
&=1-{1\over2}\sin^22\theta\\
&\ge1-{1\over2}\\
&={1\over2}
\end{align}$$

Comment: @yehushua, I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

To bound the trigonometric part:
$$\cos^4 \theta + \sin^4 \theta = \cdots = \frac{\cos 4t + 3}{4}$$
So this factor lies between $1/2$ and $1$ (See Barry Cipra's answer to derive this lower bound).

It then suffices to show that:
$$\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{e^{-1/r^2}}{r^4}= 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way of getting
Barry Cipra's result:

$c^4+s^4
=c^4+(1-c^2)^2
=c^4+1-2c^2+c^4
=1+2c^4-2c^2
=1-2c^2(1-c^2)
\ge 1/2
$
since
$x(1-x) \le 1/4$
for $0\le x \le 1$.